# Should I use client component or server component?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have an api endpoint **/api/menu.js**

I want to get menu from api and when i hover over an item, i want to get submenu now my question is that I am confused between using server or client component and also if the menu and submenu should be loaded together or just the menu and when on hover the submenu. I am using NextJS 13.5.3 and i am still learning so i am very confused about this.

I tried to create a Navbar.js file and use client but i am confused whether its a good or bad practice

```js
"use client";
    
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Navbar() {
    const [menuData, setMenuData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(
                    `api`
                );

                const data = await response.json();
                setMenuData(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
            }
        }

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    {menuData
                        .filter((item) => item.index === "menu")
                        .map((menuItem) => (
                            <Link
                                key={menuItem.sn}
                                href={menuItem.content}
                                className="px-2 py-1 transition-all hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-stone-900 relative cursor-pointer"
                            >
                                {menuItem.heading}
                            </Link>
                        ))}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with the Server Component because, with the server component, you'll be sending zero javascript to the client and you are not doing anything that holds state or changing things like events on click, change, creating context, using context, etc.

So, your Navbar Server Component would be,

```js
import Link from "next/link";
    
export default async function Navbar() {
 const response = await fetch(`....domain.name/api/menu`);
    
 if (!response.ok) {
     console.error("Error fetching menu data");
 }
    
 const menuData = await response.json();
    
 return (
        <>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    {menuData
                        .filter((item) => item.index === "menu")
                        .map((menuItem) => (
                            <Link
                                key={menuItem.sn}
                                href={menuItem.content}
                                className="px-2 py-1 transition-all hover:bg-slate-50 hover:text-stone-900 relative cursor-pointer"
                            >
                                {menuItem.heading}
                            </Link>
                        ))}
                </ul>
          </nav>
      </>
  )
}
```

I would always recommend fetching data on the server component and pass the menuData to a child component. That child component could be a client component or another server component based on what you are doing. For a better visualization, here is a [blog](https://vercel.com/blog/understanding-react-server-components) from vercel.

Comment: I've a question if you don't mind. but isn't this code the same as he posted? I mean what is the difference from the provided code to make it run on the server?

Comment: Thank you, @AmrKhaled for the questions. Regarding your first question, yes this code same but I have shown the RSC way that is nowadays used and recommended. And on your second question, the difference is that with the provided code useStates, useEffect is unnecessary and does nothing in that component. So, fetching data on the client side has to download the JavaScript before working. On the other hand, RSC doesn't.

Comment: Thanks alot for this detailed answer.

Comment: @GolamrabbiAzad but what if I want to show submenu from same Api, I should be using use client for it right? and won't I be needing use effect to show sub menu on hover or is there are any other way

Comment: Regarding your first question, yes you just pass the data to a client component. You need a client component for example when you click a button to show a modal, on hover to show a card, upload an image, handle forms, and React hooks, and simply I would say `window` object in your hand. Second, It is on you how you design your sub-menu I mean build by yourself or by using a component library.